# If $S\subset\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ is a smooth submanifold and $x\in S\Rightarrow x(m+1)=\ldots=x(m+n)=0$, is $S\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ a submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, submanifold

Given $S\subset \mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ a smooth submanifold, i.e. for all $x\in S$ there exists an open $A\ni x$, open $B\ni 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ and smooth diffeomorphism $f:A\rightarrow B$ such that $f(A\cap S)=(\mathbb{R}^d\times\{0\})\cap B$ for $d$  is the dimension of $S$, and also satisfying $x\in S\Rightarrow x_{m+1}\ldots=x_{m+n}=0$, so $S$ really lies on the $x_1\ldots x_m$ plane, is the projection of $S$ onto $\mathbb{R}^m$ a submanifold?

My intuition says yes but so far I can't even prove that it's a manifold.

Comment: I don't think so in general

Comment: When you write $x(m+1)$, do you mean $x_{m+1}$, the $m+1$th coordinate of $x$?

Comment: Yes, but for clarity I've edited it now.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean that $S$ is a submanifold of some $m + n$ dimensional manifold $X$?

Comment: It's a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$.

Comment: $S$ already lies inside $\mathbb{R}^m$, so the projection is just $S$ itself, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say the dimension of $S$ is $k$. Consider a point $s$ on $S$. We can take $k$ coordinates $x_{i_1}$, $\ldots$, $x_{i_k}$ so that around $s$ $S$ will be the graph a smooth function $\phi: \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^{m+n-k}$. Since the last $n$ coordinates of any point in $S$ are $0$ we must have
$\{i_1, \ldots, i_k\} \subset \{1, \ldots, m\}$. The $m-k$ components of $\phi$ that are of $\mathbb{R}^m$ will produce a smooth function $\psi$ so that $S$ is the graph of $\psi \colon \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^{m-k}$.

Hence $S$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

In general: if $S \subset M$ and $M$ is a submanifold of $M'$, then $S$ is a submanifold of $M'$ if and only if $S$ is a  ubmanifold of $M$.  It can be reduced the the particular case above. The main ideas:  a submanifold is locally the graph of a smooth function, and, for a function $\phi = ( \psi, 0)$, $\phi$ is smooth if and only if $\psi$ is smooth.

Comment: Do you have a reference for your first claim?

Comment: @Pepe Silvia:: Consider a point $s$ of $S$. To see what coordinates work : look at the tangent space of $S$ at $s$, which is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^N$. It has dimension $k$. Take a basis of $k$ vectors. Some $k\times  k $ minor of the matrix formed by these vectors is non-zero. Take the corresponding components as your $x_{i}$'s.  Now you know how to find the $l$ components. I don't have a reference, but the main idea is: a submanifold is locally the graph of a function. Should follow from the implicit function theorem plus some basic stuff.

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to wrap my head around it, but you put me on the right track. Thanks!